# What happens when I send a git request to a Malicious Site?

Tags: git

So I mistyped a command. I wanted to do the Angular tutorial, so I did the following:

```
git clone --depth=14 https://github.om/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

There was a typo when I used `github.om` instead of `github.com`.

Curious, I visited the site. I'm on Mac OS X // Safari, so it did one of those phony "You have a virus! Have an inescapable dialog box."

So this made me wonder... What happens when you send a git request to a malicious site? What sort of things can they learn about your system, your user information, etc.?

Also, what if I used `sudo` to complete this command -- let's say that I was on a guest account. What **else** could they learn from that? Does that change anything?

Comment: Side note: If you were cloning over SSH, it would've asked you to confirm the host key, which has the side effect of telling you you're connecting to the wrong site.

Comment: I am too tired to write a full answer, but everything you need to know is [in the protocol specification](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols). TL;DR: The worst that could happen is that it pushes you malicious sourcecode, hoping that you compile and run it.

Comment: @JaredHooper Maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *worst* that can happen, is that you may have a security bug you don't know about in your git client, and the remote you accidentally connected to may host a specially crafted repository to take advantage of it, and you will be pwned.

Unlikely? Yes. But there has been at least one [git vulnerability allowing remote code execution during a clone](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/12/critical-git-bug-allows-malicious-code-execution-on-client-machines/) in the past. And git, like any network-enabled software of sufficient complexity, has had [its share of security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-4008/GIT.html).

If you're running with `sudo`, obviously remote code execution could be far worse than normal. So maybe avoid doing that in the future if you can.